# Каким способом можно применить программу ко всем файлам и сохранить результат?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Мне необходимо применить вот эту программу

```
 = r"Details.csv"
(pd
 .read_csv(tweet_ids, skipinitialspace=True)
 .query("Language == 'ru'")
 .to_csv(r"result.csv", index=False))
```

...ко всем csv-файлам, которые имеются у меня на компьютере и которые имеют следующую иерархию: в общей папке `tweets` содержатся множество папок (`tweets_mearz` или `tweets_februar` и так далее, в которых в каждой из этих папок содержатся множество csv-файлов). На компьютере это выглядит вот так:

```
 */tweets/tweets_maerz/2021_03_14_00_Summary_Details.csv  /tweets/tweets_februar/2021_03_14_00_Summary_Details.csv*
```

и так далее.
Каждая из этих папок содержит множество csv-файлов, которые выглядят вот так:

```
    Tweet_ID,Language,Geolocation_coordinate,RT,Likes,Retweets,Country,Date Created
    1371029087414849536,en,NO,YES,0,48,"",Sun Mar 14 09:23:01 +0000 2021
    1371031318583255050,en,NO,YES,0,50,"",Sun Mar 14 09:31:53 +0000 2021
    1371031876450676736,en,NO,YES,0,51,"",Sun Mar 14 09:34:06 +0000 2021
    1371034134517256195,in,NO,YES,0,48,"",Sun Mar 14 09:43:04 +0000 2021
    1371036881622859777,en,NO,YES,0,51,"",Sun Mar 14 09:53:59 +0000 2021
```

Описанная вверху программа собирает из файла только те строчки, которые имеют атрибут `ru`. Но так как файлов очень много, то мне хотелось бы, чтобы программа проходила по каждой папке (как например `tweets_march` и `tweets_februar`) внутри папки `tweets` и соответственно ко всем csv-файлам и сохранила бы строчки с атрибутом "ru" как один csv-файл на моем компьютере. Результатом должен быть один csv-файл, со всеми строчками с атрибутом "ru":

```
    1371415898528092164,ru,NO,NO,0,0,,Mon Mar 15 11:00:04 +0000 2021
    1371415934162833408,ru,NO,NO,0,0,,Mon Mar 15 11:00:13 +0000 2021
    1371415963455909895,ru,NO,NO,0,0,,Mon Mar 15 11:00:20 +0000 2021
    1371416278229995528,ru,NO,NO,0,0,,Mon Mar 15 11:01:35 +0000 2021
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r"/path/to/data_directory")

qry = "Language == 'ru'"
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).query(qry)
                for f in path.rglob("*.csv")], 
               ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Мне выдаётся следующее сообщение:<ipython-input-16-a283502bd059>:4: DtypeWarning: Columns (6) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).query(qry)